# Check that multiple values do not exist in array column?

Tags: sql, arrays, string, postgresql, where-clause

I'm trying to build a query that returns records that have a `character varying[]` column that **does not** contain *multiple values*? Something like:

`WHERE {char1,char2,char3} != ALL(char_array_col)`

Any help appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your multiple values in an array, you can do:

```
where not myarray  @> array['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

This ensures that `myarray` does not contain all of the values.

On the other hand, if you want to ensure that `myarray` does not contain *any* of the values, use overlap operator `&&`:

```
where not myarray  && array['val1', 'val2', 'val3']
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately I get syntax errors when trying either of those. The latter one is the one I need. `"No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts."`

Comment: @tom_nb_ny: so just `cast`: `where not myarray  && array['val1', 'val2', 'val3']::character varying[]`

Comment: @tom_nb_ny: please share the entire error message.

Comment: I fiddled around and got it to execute -  `pet IS NULL OR NOT pet && '{cat,dog}'` worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @tom_nb_ny: mm ok, so that's implicit conversion of the string on the left side of the operator to an array. Fine.